# Does Linux Mint 17.1 includes GNOME?

Tags: linux-mint, gnome3, desktop-environment

I am preparing to install Mint in my machine and wondering whether the latest edition of Mint(i.e Linux Mint 17.1 Rebecca) ships with GNOME 3.16?

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint 17.1 only "ships" with `Cinnamon`, `MATE`, `KDE` and `Xfce`, but you can install `GNOME` afterwards.

Comment: Do all of them will be available in each copy of Mint?

Comment: @RogUE From what I know, there will be only one window manager included in each .iso image, but the rest are available from repository.

Comment: Sounds a little bad.